# Mysql on iMac : command not found

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, mysql-cli

I have a problem installing mysql on my Mac. I followed a tutorial, but I did not succeed.
So after having downloaded version 8.0.26 (which can be found in my system preferences), I went to the terminal to finalize all this.
I used the following steps:

```sh
cd /usr/local/mysql
sudo ./bin/mysqld_safe
```

I enter my password if required, then:

```
Ctrl + Z
bg
Ctrl + D
```

I exited the terminal, then I relaunched and typed:

```sh
% echo 'export PATH = /usr/local/mysql/bin: $ PATH' >> ~ /.profile
```

At the next step, when I am asked to type:

```sh
% mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

I have an error message saying `command not found: mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

`echo 'export PATH = / usr / local / mysql / bin: $ PATH' >> ~ / .profile`

Did you enter it like shown? With spaces between the path components?

If that is the case add the correct path (assuming your mysql binary is under /usr/local/mysql/bin) to your profile (`echo 'export PATH = /usr/local/mysql/bin: $ PATH' >> ~/.profile`).

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer.
I entered it without space (like your exemple).

After this

```
Type Ctrl + Z
bg
Type Ctrl + D
```

when I want to quit the Terminal, I have to stop the process and click "Finish" so I don't know if it works.